# Dynamic query based on value of query params in java

Tags: java

I want to write a dynamic query based on value of query params. I have string query like this

```
String strSQL = "select tb_r_orderdata.customerid,\n" +
                            "REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(finishtime,10),'-',''),':',''),'T','') as paydate,\n" +
                            "tb_r_orderdata.amount,\n" +
                            "tb_r_orderdata.acquirementid,\n" +
                            "tb_r_orderdata.tracking_ref,\n" +
                            "tb_m_biller_product.billerdesc, \n" +
                            "tb_m_biller_product.productdesc, \n" +
                            "tb_r_orderdata.hpno, \n" +
                            "tb_r_orderdata.email, \n" +
                            "tb_r_orderdata.rc, \n" +
                            "tb_r_orderdata.rcdesc, \n" +
                            "tb_r_orderdata.additionaldata_pay \n" +
                            "from tb_r_orderdata JOIN tb_m_biller_product ON tb_r_orderdata.productid=tb_m_biller_product.productid AND tb_r_orderdata.billerid=tb_m_biller_product.billerid \n" +
                            "where status='SUCCESS';";
```

The result like this, if there is value or not in query params, the string query will added based on the condition.

Here is my condition

```
String newstrSQL = strSQL;
PreparedStatement pst=null;

if (period != null) {
   newstrSQL = strSQL + "and REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(finishtime,10),'-',''),':',''),'T','')>=?";
}

if (tanggal != null) {
    newstrSQL = strSQL + "and REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(finishtime,10),'-',''),':',''),'T','')<=?";
}

if (billerid != null) {
    newstrSQL = strSQL + "and tb_m_biller_product.billerid  = ?";
}

if (productid != null) {
    newstrSQL = strSQL + "and tb_m_biller_product.productid  = ?";
}

if (custom != null) {
    newstrSQL = strSQL + "and" + searchby + " = ?";
}

pst = con.prepareStatement(newstrSQL);
pst.setString(1, period);
pst.setString(2, tanggal);
pst.setString(3, billerid);
pst.setString(4, productid);
pst.setString(5, custom);

rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

I have test it, but the result always zero and there is not syntax error. Thank you, sorry for bad English

Comment: if `period` is `null` do you still want to call `pst.setString(1, period);` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have given semicolon in string `where status='SUCCESS';`, It means your query ends here and the remaining you appending after it will not execute as you are trying here `strSQL + "and REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(finishtime,10),'-',''),':',''),'T','')>=?";`.

Don't end strSql with semicolon and try.

Comment: i have try what you say, but still not get the data @Tejendra.

Comment: then check your final query  by printing it, if it contain any deficiency. Here you are considering all your  if conditions will be true .

Comment: i have try it but only display `......and ? = ?;` . i want that if 2 or morecondition true . like this for example two condition true then the result like `.... and ?= ? and REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(finishtime,10),'-',''),':',''),'T','')>=?;` @Tejendra